# Titan unable to connect to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, titan

[image]

I'm trying to code to connect Tital to this Cassandra with this code:

```
    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.build()
            .set("storage.backend","cassandra")
            .set("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1")
            .open();
```

However, I am getting this **error**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
>   not instantiate implementation:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
>     at com.txtstreet.bucket.TitanExample.main(TitanExample.java:59)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
>     ... 7 more Caused by:
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException:
>   Temporary failure in storage backend  at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:572)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:291)
>     ... 12 more Caused by:
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException:
>   PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160,
>   latency=10003(10003), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:198)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:84)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.internalCreateKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:321)
>     at
>   com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:567)
>     ... 13 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enable Thrift server of Cassandra**

Use the below command to enable thrift

```
nodetool enablethrift
```